# Finding the max dict value of a 3-level nested dict

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have a 3-level nested dict and I would like to find the max value of the 3rd-level dict and have it mapped to the 2nd-level key it belongs to. For example, In "Loc-1" dict value, there are two 2nd-level keys that are "36", I want this key mapped to the value "56".

This is the dict:

```
{
    "Loc-1": {
        "A-1": {"36" : {"value" : "34"}},
        "A-2": {"36" : {"value" : "56"}},
        "A-3": {"48" : {"value" : "72"}},
        "A-4": {"100" : {"value" : "77"}},
        "A-5": {"48" : {"value" : "2"}},
        "A-6": {"100" : {"value" : "10"}},
        "A-7": {"44" : {"value": "21"}}
        
    }
    
    "Loc-2": {
        "A-8": {"44" : {"value" : "52"}},
        "A-9": {"48" : {"value" : "23"}},
        "A-10": {"40" : {"value" : "62"}},
        "A-11": {"153" : {"value" : "43"}},
        "A-12": {"40" : {"value" : "22"}},
        "A-13": {"153" : {"value" : "10"}},
        "A-14": {"36" : {"value": "21"}}
        
    }

}
```

This is the desired state:

```
{ 
    "Loc-1": {   
        "36" : "56",
        "48" : "72",
        "100": "77",
        "44" : "21"
        
    }
    
    "Loc-2": { 
        "36" : "21",
        "40" : "62",
        "48" : "23",
        "44" : "52",
        "153": "43",
        
    }
    
}
```

I'm finding it hard to compare one value to all the other values with the same key when it nested like this. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Why is `"40" : "72",` in the results for `Site-1`?

Comment: Please clarify your question. Your example output doesn't seem to be calculating any maximums. In your case, 3 levels isn't so deep that it can't be handled with nested for loops. However, if you need a general solution, I recommend using recursion. Additionally, are you familiar with how to loop through a dictionary (`for key in data`, `for key, value in data.items()`)?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I removed the `"40" : "72"`. You're right that should not be there.

Comment: @MichaelSohnen I am aware of how to loop through a dict, but the problem is when im looping through the 3rd level dict, how do i compare the value in the 3rd-level dict to other 3rd-level values with similar 2nd level key? I'm struggling with that part.

Comment: @BuG I typically handle this by making a custom class that functions like a dictionary. I then implement an insert function, something like `def insert(key,value): if key not in self.internal_dict: self.internal_dict[key] = [value]; else: self.internal_dict[key].append(value)`. After you've collected the values, you can take whichever statistics you want (max, min, mean, median, mode, etc.). Make an instance of this class for each second level dict, then loop through each second level dict and insert `"value"` from the corresponding third level dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested loops will work:

```
results = {}

# 1st level: "Loc-1", "Loc-2"
for key1 in data:
    # Initialize to empty dictionary
    results[key1] = {}
    # 2nd level: A-1, A-2, etc
    for key2 in data[key1]:
        # First key 3rd level: 38, 36, etc
        key3 = next(iter(data[key1][key2]))
        value = data[key1][key2][key3]["value"]
        # Set max if already in results or just add
        if key3 in results[key1]:
            results[key1][key3] = max(results[key1][key3], value)
        else:
            results[key1][key3] = value
```

Comment: thank you! May I ask why you used `key3 = next(iter(data[key1][key2]))` instead of `for key3 in data[key1][key2]:`

Comment: I only did that because there was just one key in the sample data. If there is more than one, then, yes, use a loop.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can do the following.

```
def process(d):
    def process_(dic_1st_level):
        ' Get max values from 2nd level dics '
        result = {}
        for a, d_2nd_level in dic_1st_level.items():
            for label, v in d_2nd_level.items():
                result[label] = max(result.get(label, 0), v['value'], key = int)

        # Sort result by key as ints
        return dict(sorted(result.items(), key = lambda kv: int(kv[0])))

    return {k.replace("Loc", "Site"):process_(v) for k, v in d.items()}
```

**Usage**

```
print(process(d))   # d is the input nested dictionary
```

**Output**

```
{
    "Site-1": {
        "36": "56",
        "44": "21",
        "48": "72",
        "100": "77"
    },
    "Site-2": {
        "36": "21",
        "40": "62",
        "44": "52",
        "48": "23",
        "153": "43"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the easy, inner-most dictionary first and work our way out to the outer dictionary. I will call the inner most dictionary simply `dict_object`, e.g. `{"36" : {"value" : "34"}}`. In order to work with this dictionary, I find it easier to transform it into a simpler structure: A tuple with two elements: `("36", "34")`. For that, I created a function called `transform_value`:

```py
def transform_value(dict_object):
    """Transform {"36" : {"value" : "34"}} --> ("36", "34")."""
    for key, value in dict_object.items():
        return key, value["value"]

# Test it out
>>> transform_value({"36" : {"value" : "34"}})
('36', '34')
```

Next, I also need to compare two strings numerically and return the larger one:

```py
def maxint(a, b):
    """Take max of two strings which represents two ints."""
    return str(max(int(a), int(b)))

# Test it out:
>>> maxint("34", "56")
'56'
```

Working out (or up) one more level, the level with the 'Loc-1' values:

```py
def transform_loc(loc_values):
    transformed = {}
    for dict_object in loc_values:
        key, value = transform_value(dict_object)
        transformed.setdefault(key, value)
        transformed[key] = maxint(transformed[key], value)
    return transformed

# Test it out, let's call the original structure `data`
>>> transform_loc(data["Loc-1"].values())
{'36': '56', '48': '72', '100': '77', '44': '21'}
```

Putting it all together:

```py
new_data = {
    key: transform_loc(loc.values())
    for key, loc in data.items()
}

# New data is
{
    "Loc-1": {
        "36": "56",
        "48": "72",
        "100": "77",
        "44": "21"
    },
    "Loc-2": {
        "44": "52",
        "48": "23",
        "40": "62",
        "153": "43",
        "36": "21"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer! I will be testing this out.